# OpenCV python: ValueError: too many values to unpack , img

Tags: python, computer-vision, cvzone

I am writing an opencv project which is a fingers distance finder and making an image(its complicated to explain but I try my best.

When i run the script, I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/P4rakash_Python_Projects/Python Projects/adding things/python.py", line 16, in <module>
    hands, img2 = detector.findHands(img)
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
[ WARN:0] global D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (438) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback
```

I dont understand this error if someone fix this and answer me I can get the hang off it.

this is the full code

```
from cv2 import cv2
from cvzone.HandTrackingModule import HandDetector

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3, 1280)
cap.set(4, 720)

detector = HandDetector(detectionCon=0.8)

startDist = None

scale = 0.
cx, cy = 500, 500
while True:
    Success, img = cap.read()
    hands, img = detector.findHands(img)
    img1 = cv2.imread("kisspng-computer-icons-code-coupon-font-computer-coding-5b4cbf4c6bb012.9457556415317563644411.png")

    if len(hands) == 2:
        # print(detector.fingersUp(hands[0]), detector.fingersUp(hands[1]))
        if detector.fingersUp(hands[0]) == [1, 1, 0, 0, 0] and detector.fingersUp(hands[1]) == [1, 1, 0, 0, 0]:
            # print("ZOOMMING GESTUREs")
            lmList1 = hands[0]["lmList"]
            lmList2 = hands[1]["lmList"]

            # Point 8 is teh tip of the finger
            if startDist is None:
                length, info, img = detector.findDistance(lmList1[8], lmList2[8], img)

                startDist = length

            length, info, img = detector.findDistance(lmList1[8], lmList2[8], img)
            scale = int((length - startDist) // 2)
            cx, cy = info[4:]
            # print(scale)
    else:
        startDist = None
    try:
        h1, w1, _ = img1.shape
        newH, newW = ((h1 + scale) // 2) * 2, ((w1 + scale) // 2) * 2
        img1 = cv2.resize(img1, (newW, newH))

        img[cy - newH // 2:cy + newH // 2, cx - newW // 2:cx + newW // 2] = img1

    except:
        pass

    img = cv2.flip(img, 1)
    cv2.imshow("Hollow.os", img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

when I do this code there is a warning coming called `Unexpected argument`

help is mostly what I want now

Comment: there must be documentation for `detector.findHands`. kindly look it up ?

Comment: "help is mostly what I want now" -- why not try yourself: `help(detector.findHands)` ?

Comment: ok I am trying on my side too if I find anything I will surely post it

Answer (score 2):

That's because `findhands` returns only 1 value, not 2.

The right syntax would be

```
img2 = detector.findHands(img)
```

Comment: so can u tell me the correct way to do it

Comment: dude whats will be the correct code then

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I been using a 1.4.1 cvzone library to make the findposition to work then I changed it back.  And this works just fine

```
Change your cvzone library version to 1.5.6 so the code will work.
```

please check your cvzone version because if this error comes for you then change it to the latest version it works fine now

Answer (score 1):

If we print for example `lmList1[8]`:

```py
print(lmList1[8]) # It will give us 3 values not 2
```

In the `findDistance`:

```py
x1, y1 = p1 # This is wrong
x1, y1, z1 = p # It should be like this
```

```py
x1, y1, z1 = p1
x2, y2, z2 = p2
```

---

Another solution, is you can keep the `findDistance` as it is and change the line of code into:

```
length, info, img = detector.findDistance(lmList1[8][:2], lmList2[8][:2], img)
```

This will take only the first 2 values `x1, y1` and `x2,y2`.

Answer (score 0):

cvzone version needs to be upgraded. The following steps can be followed,

1. check the current cvzone version

   ```
   pip freeze
   ```
2. Upgrade the version

   ```
   pip install cvzone -U
   ```

For my case, previous=>  cvzone==1.4.1 then
Successfully *uninstalled* **cvzone-1.4.1**
*Successfully installed* **cvzone-1.5.6**

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the cvzone library version 1.5.6 and still face the issue try this:

```
length, info, frame = detector.findDistance(lmList[8][0:2], lmList[12][0:2], frame)
```

The full code would look like this:

```
from cvzone.HandTrackingModule import HandDetector
import cv2

detector = HandDetector()
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    _, frame = cap.read()
    hands, frame = detector.findHands(frame)

    if hands:
        hand = hands[0]
        lmList = hand["lmList"]
        length, info, frame = detector.findDistance(
            lmList[8][0:2], lmList[12][0:2], frame
        )
        print(length)

    cv2.imshow("Video", frame)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```